# Using senders independent in Symfony messenger component

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-messenger

I'm using Symfony 4.2 and have one message to dispatch via messenger component which is a notification that should be sent via a few channels (for example SMS and email). I'm wondering how to make these senders independent (for example first channel fails and throw an exception) - how to make a try to send independent via the second sender? Currently, when one of the senders in the chain fails the rest can't make a try of delivering notification.

Catching exception on the sender level seems not to be a good solution, because returning envelop causes that it will be stamped as sent what is not true.

I've started to make message per channel to keep sentStamp convention, but It seems that should be one message and few channels listening for one message (even configuration indicates to that with `senders` keyword):

```
routing:
        'App\Messenger\Command\Notification\SendSomeInformation':
            senders:
                - App\Messenger\Sender\Notification\EmailSender
                - App\Messenger\Sender\Notification\SmsSender
```

There is some good approach for such problem?

Comment: I have to admit I didn't know you could specify specific senders per message type. Can't find it in the docs either, but it's seems very neat. I just use regular handlers for this, but this configuration might be advantageous.

Comment: @yivi https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/messenger.html#routing last code example in that paragraph

Comment: Huh, those options are no longer available in newer versions of the documentation, I wonder if they were removed. Something to keep in mind if you plan on ever upgrading.

Comment: @yivi It seems to be available https://symfony.com/doc/master/messenger.html#routing-messages-to-a-transport

Comment: In that second link, I see no example like the one in the 4.2 version. Am I missing it?

Comment: @yivi Maybe it's not in the same form, but you can pass an array of senders (see `'My\Message\ToBeSentToTwoSenders': [async, audit]`)

Comment: Although those are _transports_, not _senders_. Those are different things. In the example you show from 4.2 documentation you can configure both things (transports and senders). But that's not shown in the latest version.

Comment: @yivi Seems to [still be available in 5.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/76c22fab021c006262a6ef20532c052072a2cebe/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L1202).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to configure two different transports, and assign each handler to different transports, so if one of them fails and dequeues the message, the other can still have a chance to run.

```
# config/packages/messenger.yaml
transports:
    async1:
        # dsn
    async2:
        # dsn
...
routing:
    'App\Messenger\Command\Notification\SendSomeInformation': [async1, async2]
```

Restricting handlers to transports can be done either [in code or config](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#binding-handlers-to-different-transports), choose what works better for you.

In config:

```
# config/services.yaml
App\Messenger\Sender\Notification\SmsSender:
    tags: 
        - { name: 'messenger.message_handler', from_transport: 'async1'}
```